# Can Pix intercept Caitlyn's ultimate?

Tags: league-of-legends

As Caitlyn, I used my ultimate on a very low health Lulu that had her skills (including her ultimate) on cooldown. She started to run away, my ultimate went off, and my ultimate did not hurt her even one bit.

She and I couldn't believe what happened. We came to the conclusion that Pixie had intercepted the ultimate, but I'm still not sure. Is this possible?

Comment: Haha, I am starting to like playing Lulu even more :D

Comment: @James >.> Not funny at all. :p

Comment: Asking whether or not something is a bug is a bad question. Rather, ask how the game works. Whatever happens happens, and we can't get inside the developers' minds to figure out if it was intended or not.

Comment: +1 for @StrixVaria he is right (idk WHY I ALWAYS think of you as a girl... o.O)

Comment: I did a "bump" on your post @Marcelo on the Bug forum. hope someone could help it =)

Answer (score 4):

After some rigorous testing with my friend Zamual05, we've managed to determine that Pix does **not** intercept Caitlyn's ultimate.

We tried two different variations, to include Lulu running away (placing Pix behind her, in direct line of the shot), and Lulu standing still; in both attempts, Lulu took the damage directly with no interception from Pix.

In conclusion, **no**. Pix should *not* intercept Caitlyn's ultimate. What you experienced is definitely a bug.

Comment: @Tristan thanks guys, it hasn't happened again for me, but I still reported the bug (still no answer). It will probably be difficult to find for Riot if there really is one.

Answer (score 2):

Pix has no health bar, so it will be impossible her to intercept it. It's probably a bug. You should probably report it on [league of legends bug forum](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/forumdisplay.php?f=3)

You can use Yorick's minions to intercept it for example (because they are champions skills and have health bar).

Comment: Yeah, Pix in terms of a unit probably doesn't even have a hitbox so I think that must be a bug. Who the in the world would want to kill Pix anyway?! Also, I think I smell something...... science!

Comment: Also, when you use "Help, Pix" and the opponent pass by a Turret, the turret does not attack Pix

Comment: @Emerica, i've seen you use that term several times now. Is it a reference to something? I seem to be missing something. Science?

Comment: @Jay This is all I could find http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=for+science

Comment: @MichelAyres Thank you. I have submitted the issue to the bug forum. http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=1942849

Comment: @Marcelo Please, when you get a reply, post the link here, will help other users too =)

Comment: @Jay Science is used when one doesn't have a definitive answer to a question, so you test it yourself in game. I'm at work right now, but if someone doesn't get to the bottom of this by the time I get home I will do some science.

Comment: @Emerica ah okay. i have both cait and lulu so I am willing to test later tonight when i get home from work also.

Comment: I have Lulu only =P