# Can you block Caitlyn's ult with neutral minions?

Tags: league-of-legends

I was wondering if Caitlyn ults you can you run behind neutral minions such as baron or dragon to block it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Caitlyn's ult can be blocked by any champion if he steps in between Caitlyn and her target. In addition, her ult can be blocked by

- Shaco's Hallucination Clone
- Mordekaiser's Children of the Grave Clone
- Yorick's Omen of Death Clone
- Leblanc's Mirror Image Clone
- Wukong's Decoy Clone

Note that certain pets cannot block Caitlyn's ult. These include

- Annie's Tibbers
- Yorick's Omens, not including Omen of Death
- Malzahar's Voidling
- Lulu's Pix (Thanks Fluttershy!)
- Orianna's Pet Ball
- Viktor's Chaos Storm
- Heimerdingers H28-G Evolution Turret
- Maokai's Sapling
- Shaco's Jack in the Box

Comment: For further reference: [Pix can't either!](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/57578/can-pix-intercept-caitlyns-ultimate)

Comment: Also, Zyra's plants can't

Answer (score 6):

Caitlyn's ult only accepts champions as targets. You can only dodge it by hiding behind another champion. So, no. You can not hide behind anything that isn't a champion or a copy of a champion (the only units that arent champions, but are classed as champions, would be copies, such as Shaco's hallucination, Leblanc's Mirror Image etc. Basically, everything that looks like a champion.).

Answer (score 1):

Caitlyn's Ult can not be blocked by Baron or Dragon. Only by champions and copies of champions(Shaco's Halluciantion Clone, Leblanc's passive Mirror Image Clone, ect.)

Simply nothing will block it unless it is a champion or resembles a champion.